# Keep specific sub-cells of a cell applying cellfun

Tags: matlab

I have for example this cell:

```
c = { {'c1_str1','c1_str2'},{'c2_str1','c2_str2','c2_str3','c2_str4'}, {'c3_str1','c3_str2'}
```

and I want to to filter `c` to take the `cc` cell:

```
cc = {'c1_str2', 'c2_str2','c2_str3','c2_str4', 'c3_str2'}
```

In other words, I want for each sub-cell od `c` to keep the all the elements except the first one.

I have tried:

```
cc = cellfun(@(x)[x{2:end}],c,'UniformOutput',0);
cc = cellfun(@(x)[x(2:end)],c,'UniformOutput',0);
```

but without success. Because `c` is big enough, could you please someone make a suggestion how can we do it using `cellfun` avoiding for loop implementation:

```
cc = {};
for i = 1:numel(c)
    cc= [cc c{i}(2:end)]; 
end
```

Thanks!

**PS:** Any suggestion to keep sub-cell in an arbitrary positions (for example the first second and fifth sub-cell) it would be very interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it:

```
cc = cellfun(@(x) x(2:end),c,'UniformOutput',0);
cc = [cc{:}]
```

The arbitrary version is a little trickier:

```
idx = [1,2,5]

cc = cellfun( @(x)  x( idx(idx<=numel(c)) ),c,'uni',0 )
cc = [cc{:}]
```

Comment: @Thoth added the arbitrary version also

Comment: +1 You can change `cellfun(@(x) {x{2:end}}, c, 'UniformOutput',0)` to the slightly simpler `cellfun(@(x) x(2:end) , c, 'UniformOutput',0)`